# How to plot intervals in a cartopy map?

Tags: python, pandas, cartopy

I have this df:

```
     CODE      STATION     LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  INTERVAL
0    109014   BUENA VISTA  -9.433706 -78.208250  [25, 30)
1    111022        HUAYAN -11.452808 -77.122006  [25, 30)
2    111023          ﾑAﾑA -11.987444 -76.841944  [25, 30)
3    112058       PACARAN -12.866892 -76.057928  [25, 30)
4    111004  ALCANTARILLA -11.060681 -77.550106  [20, 25)
..      ...           ...        ...        ...       ...
264  114050        ANANEA -14.676278 -69.533855  [15, 20)
265  113100  VILCASHUAMAN -13.668877 -73.952427  [15, 20)
266  113101     CHILCAYOC -13.882978 -73.726799  [15, 20)
267  114093        PUTINA -14.921000 -69.875700  [15, 20)
268  114096     CUYO CUYO -14.488841 -69.550035  [15, 20)
```

Interval column is a categorical type.

I want to plot points in a map based on intervals with different markers.

For interval [25,30) a red triangle, for interval [20,25) a green square, etc etc. So i'm trying this code:

```
fig = plt.figure('map', figsize=(7,7), dpi=200)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.80, 0.75], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.xlabel('LONGITUD') 
plt.ylabel('LATITUD') 

l1 = NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries', scale='50m', facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(l1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)


img1 = ax.scatter(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE, s=6,c=df.INTERVAL,
                 marker='o',cmap='RdYlGn_r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I'm just plotting 1 marker and also i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would a plotly answer be acceptable?

Comment: I need to do it in a cartopy map, srry

Comment: ok - `fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", color="INTERVAL")
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")` would generate you different color markers for intervals in plotly

Answer (score 1):

You should give c  a color-related information rather than a categorical type.